# All hard drives spinning up even though only accessing system SSD

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, windows-10

This problem is quite annoying. I've just upgraded to Windows 10 and although I experienced it a bit in Windows 7, it seems much worse in 10. I have 2 SSDS (one C drive for Windows and another for apps), plus 3 Western Digital external USB drives and a WD Black 2TB. If the system has been idle for enough time for the drives to spin down, I'll open something like my email client (eMClient) and it will cause all these drives (well, I think all. Obviously a bit hard to tell, but I can hear at least 2-3 starting up) to spin up before it opens, sometimes taking up to 10 seconds. This will be for software that doesn't have links to those drives, hence the mystery. I would understand it if I had saved files on those drives, but it is for software that is entirely contained on the system drive. Obviously this is very annoying and negates the speed advantage of an SSD when I have to wait for platter drives to spin up. I hope that makes sense and grateful for any insight. Cheers.

Comment: eMClient is apparently closed-source, so only one of their developers could answer this (or a skilled debugger), but I'd guess they're calling some API to enumerate all storage devices, causing the spin-ups. But that's only a guess. You should probably contact their support.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not just eMClient that causes this. I'll do a bit more testing to see what else does.